# When does the Federation find out about Voyager?

Tags: star-trek, star-trek-voyager

In *Star Trek: Voyager*, which episode shows when the Federation first found out that Voyager had survived?

Comment: I thought my answer to this one was about as comprehensive is it gets. Don't forget to click the "accepted" button :-)

Answer (score 12):

The episode where Voyager makes initial contact with the Federation is [Voy: Message in a Bottle](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Message_in_a_Bottle_(episode)). The EMH is transferred onto a Federation vessel and communicates Voyager's predicament to Starfleet.

This was subsequently followed up by a two-way channel of communication in [Voy: Pathfinder](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Pathfinder_(episode)), courtesy of Reg Barclay and the MIDAS communication array.

---

It may interest you to know that prior to this episode they'd already made contact with two different Alpha Quadrant powers; A Romulan in [Voy: Eye of the Needle](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Eye_of_the_Needle_(episode)) and two Ferengi in [Voy: False Profits](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/False_Profits_(episode)) but unfortunately their situation wasn't communicated to Starfleet.